# What is the Grails GSP equivalent of ASP's ContentPlaceHolder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grails, groovy, gsp, sitemesh

I've been playing around a lot with the templating/layout concepts in Grails GSP.  I've ben using layouts/content blocks for imitating ASP's master page behavior.

For example, I am using the tag `<g:pageProperty />` in a template to leave a "placeholder" which can be overridden using a `<content>` tag:

**myTemplate.gsp:**

```
<body>
    <g:pageProperty name="page.topDiv" />
</body>
```

**myPage.gsp:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="myTemplate"></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <content tag="topDiv">
           My top div
        </content>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works great for "appending" content to some spot within a template.  However, I really want the behavior I can get in ASP.NET's master pages... which is to provide a "default" rendering of some content, and allow optional overriding.  In an ASP.NET Master page, it would look like this:

**myMaster.master:**

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="something" runat="server">
   <div>Default text/html here</div>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**someOtherPage.aspx:**

```
<asp:Content contentPlaceHolderId="something" runat="server">
    Overriden content here!!  I don't need to override this though :)
</asp:Content>
```

My Question:
**Can I do this same default/overriding behavior in Grails' GSP?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different days you could accomplish this.  The `g:pageProperty` is equivalent to the Sitemesh `decorator:getProperty` tag, so you can use a `default` attribute to indicate the default text to use.  For example:

```
<g:pageProperty name="page.topDiv" default="Default text/html here"/>
```

However, I don't know of a clean way to get HTML content in there.  You could use a `g:if` tag to test for that property and specify default behavior if it doesn't exist:

```
    <g:if test="${pageProperty(name:'page.topDiv')}">
        <g:pageProperty name="page.topDiv"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <div>Default text/html here</div>
    </g:else>
```

The default content could also live in an external template gsp.  The `render` method could then be used to display that content in the default attribute of `g:pageProperty`:

```
<g:pageProperty name="page.topDiv" default="${render(template:'topDiv')}"/>
```

Where in this case, the default content would be located in `_topDiv.gsp`.

Comment: Jason, thank you!  I didn't even think about putting a `render` call in the default attribute...  Putting the render call in the default attribute works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try  instead.

```
<g:render template=""><g:render>
```